# How to adjust style React Calendar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

```
npm install react-calendar
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';
```

I've just installed the react-calendar package using the above method. I was wondering how can I adjust the CSS of this calendar, e.g. increase the width or height? I already imported the react-calendar css.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy Calendar.css file and add your edits to it and then use it instead of original. Or create additional CSS file with override styles.

Comment: I was thinking that also, but I can't find the file when I search it in my local folder?

Comment: Use `className` prop and override styles

Comment: @micky22 look inside node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Just use the developer tools in your browser and inspect/select an element you want to style. Based on the css class, you can apply your own custom styles.

The default styles are available in `react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css` (or in the respective `.less` file).